# Completed 401 Unauthorized devise user login after sign up

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on the devise registration controller override , when i sign up with a new user ,it signs me in for the first time , but when i sign out and then try to sign in it gives me an error below in console

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"Wq8QW/F8X1BVxFcH6M9WU8OUpIGjKI1mKd1+/OBGyGY=", "user"=>  {"email"=>"jamil@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign   in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` =   'jamil@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
 **Completed 401 Unauthorized in 16ms**
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓" ,     "authenticity_token"=>"Wq8QW/F8X1BVxFcH6M9WU8OUpIGjKI1mKd1+/OBGyGY=", "user"=>     {"email"=>"jamil@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign     in"}
```

and then it gives message of invalid email or password

Please help me in this weird issue...i am hanged up

Here is my registration Form

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
```

resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do        |f| %>

```
 <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
 <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :Connector_code %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :invitation_token,:value => @token %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

   <div><%= f.label :Friends_code %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :friend_token ,:value =>params[:invitation_token]%></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
 <% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>


Thanks
```

Comment: Can you post the Sign Up registration form

Comment: ya , edited the question above

Comment: Surely you missed `<%= form_for(resource, :as =>` this by accident at the top of your form?

Comment: And usually a HTTP status code 401 is usually when `but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided` see here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes. Also you mentioned you are working on `devise/registration_controller`.

Comment: in fact i missed "<%= form_for(resource, :as =>" it while copying, so its ok in my registration form. when i sign up a new user then it signs up successfully, but when i signout and then login then it gives wrong email or password error.

Comment: What is it your trying to override in your `registration_controller`

Comment: def new
   @user=User.new
   @token=Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    puts @token
    super
  end                    this is what i have in my override controller , just trying to create a token and passing its value to a field in form.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the authentication_keys parameter either in the initializer file or the model itself:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
   config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
end
```

or

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
     :authentication_keys => [:email]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```